# jquery .click(function) not working properly

Tags: jquery, onclick

I currently have a click event with a few animations. I got the basics of what I want the animation to do. Here's what i've done. After the code break i'll explain my problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hidden').hide().removeClass('hidden');

$('.about-prj-tog').click(function(event){      
    $('#logo-wrapper').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#logo').delay(100).animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#about-prj').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    return false;
});
$('.weekly-tog').click(function(event){     
    $('#logo-wrapper').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#logo').delay(100).animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#weekly-updates').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    return false;
});
$('.submit-story-tog').click(function(event){       
    $('#logo-wrapper').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#logo').delay(100).animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    $('#submit-drop-down').animate({height:'toggle'}, 1000);
    return false;
});

$('.x-icon').click(function(event){
    $('#logo-wrapper').animate({height:'toggle'} );
    $('#logo').show();
    $('#about-prj').animate({height:'toggle'} );
    $('#weekly-updates').animate({height:'toggle'} );
    $('#submit-drop-down').animate({height:'toggle'} );
});
```

});

As you probably have seen, the problem I'm getting is that when i click the first link. The animation happens and it looks great. But if i click the next link the other animation happens below the first one. - without the first one closing first and the second animation happening and so on.

make sense?

Also any tips on consolidating the code and making it more efficient. I do realize that I wrote the same thing 3 times and just changed class and ids. If there's a better way to write *less* code that would help me understand jquery even more.

Also, when I click the .x-icon div. All sorts of craziness happens.

Comment: Set up a fiddle at jsfiddle.net make sure to choose I query framework :)

Comment: Check the jQuery [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) methods.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Can you post a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ with some relevant markup?